# Make xargs execute the command once for each line of input

Tags: xargs

How can I make xargs execute the command exactly once for each line of input given?
It's default behavior is to chunk the lines and execute the command once, passing multiple lines to each instance.

> From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs:
>
> find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rm
>
> In this example, find feeds the input of xargs with a long list of file names. xargs then splits this list into sublists and calls rm once for every sublist. This is more efficient than this functionally equivalent version:
>
> find /path -type f -exec rm '{}' \;

I know that find has the "exec" flag.  I am just quoting an illustrative example from another resource.

Comment: In the example you provide, `find /path -type f -delete` would be even more efficient :)

Comment: try not to use xargs...

Comment: OP, I know this question is very old, but it still comes up on Google and IMHO the accepted answer is wrong. See my longer answer below.

Comment: Please consider switching your accept to @Tobia's answer which is much better.  The accepted answer does not handle spaces in names and doesn't allow multiple arguments to the xargs command which is one of the main features of xargs.

Answer (score 516, accepted):

The following will only work if you do not have spaces in your input:

```
xargs -L 1
xargs --max-lines=1 # synonym for the -L option
```

from the man page:

```
-L max-lines
          Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.
          Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued  on
          the next input line.  Implies -x.
```

Comment: For me it can out as `xargs -n 1` as the one you gave showed "argument list too long".

Comment: If `MAX-LINES` is omitted it defaults to 1, thus `xargs -l` is enough. See `info xargs`.

Comment: Also useful for restoring all deleting files using git. git ls-files --deleted | xargs -L 1 git checkout --

Comment: what if you just want the first line?

Comment: @Wernight: "-n1" does not give 1 invocation per input line. maybe your input line was too long. demo: `echo "foo bar" | xargs -n1 echo`. hence if you pipe in stuff like 'ls', it won't handle spaces well.

Comment: This is wrong. `-L 1` does not answer the original question, and `-n 1` does so only in one of the possible interpretations. See my long answer below.

Comment: @Tobia: It answers the original question, which was quite specifically about lines of input. That's exactly what `-L 1` does. To me, the OP seemed to be clearly trying to avoid the default chunking behaviour, and since this was accepted I assume I was right. Your answer addresses a slightly different use-case where you want the chunking behaviour as well.

Comment: I don't like this answer.  It doesn't handle filenames with spaces in them which is a key function of the `-print0` output and issues one command per line of input which is another key function of xargs.  For example, you can't tar up multiple files and you can't tar up files with spaces in them.  See my answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30104264/179850

Comment: @Tobia's solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/28806991/1262108 is the right answer.

Comment: @Draemon it might answer the 'question' but it does not answer the 'question title'.

Comment: Perhaps we can edit this answer to include `| tr '\0' '\n' | xargs -0` or `| xargs -d '\n'` ?

Comment: This answer is incomplete; eg. on busybox systems, the option would be `-n`.

Answer (score 364):

It seems to me all existing answers on this page are wrong, including the one marked as correct. That stems from the fact that the question is ambiguously worded.

**Summary:**   If you want to execute the command *"exactly once for each line of input,"* passing the entire line (without newline) to the command as a *single argument,* then this is the best UNIX-compatible way to do it:

```
... | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 ...
```

If you are using GNU `xargs` and don't need to be compatible with all other UNIX's (FreeBSD, Mac OS X, etc.) then you can use the GNU-specific option `-d`:

```
... | xargs -d\\n -n1 ...
```

Now for the long explanation…

---

There are two issues to take into account when using xargs:

1. how does it split the input into "arguments"; and
2. how many arguments to pass the child command at a time.

To test xargs' behavior, we need an utility that shows how many times it's being executed and with how many arguments. I don't know if there is a standard utility to do that, but we can code it quite easily in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "-> "; for a in "$@"; do echo -n "\"$a\" "; done; echo
```

Assuming you save it as `show` in your current directory and make it executable, here is how it works:

```
$ ./show one two 'three and four'
-> "one" "two" "three and four"
```

Now, if the original question is really about point 2. above (as I think it is, after reading it a few times over) and it is to be read like this (changes in bold):

> *How can I make xargs execute the command exactly once for each **argument** of input given? Its default behavior is to chunk the **input into arguments** and execute the command **as few times as possible**, passing multiple **arguments** to each instance.*

then the answer is `-n 1`.

Let's compare xargs' default behavior, which splits the input around whitespace and calls the command as few times as possible:

```
$ echo one two 'three and four' | xargs ./show 
-> "one" "two" "three" "and" "four"
```

and its behavior with `-n 1`:

```
$ echo one two 'three and four' | xargs -n 1 ./show 
-> "one" 
-> "two" 
-> "three" 
-> "and" 
-> "four"
```

If, on the other hand, the original question was about point 1. input splitting and it was to be read like this (many people coming here seem to think that's the case, or are confusing the two issues):

> *How can I make xargs execute the command **with** exactly **one argument** for each line of input given? Its default behavior is to chunk the lines **around whitespace**.*

then the answer is more subtle.

One would think that `-L 1` could be of help, but it turns out it doesn't change argument parsing. It only executes the command once for each input line, with as many arguments as were there on that input line:

```
$ echo $'one\ntwo\nthree and four' | xargs -L 1 ./show 
-> "one" 
-> "two" 
-> "three" "and" "four"
```

Not only that, but if a line ends with whitespace, it is appended to the next:

```
$ echo $'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | xargs -L 1 ./show 
-> "one" "two" 
-> "three" "and" "four"
```

Clearly, `-L` is not about changing the way xargs splits the input into arguments.

The only argument that does so in a cross-platform fashion (excluding GNU extensions) is `-0`, which splits the input around NUL bytes.

Then, it's just a matter of translating newlines to NUL with the help of `tr`:

```
$ echo $'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ./show 
-> "one " "two" "three and four"
```

Now the argument parsing looks all right, including the trailing whitespace.

Finally, if you combine this technique with `-n 1`, you get exactly one command execution per input line, whatever input you have, which may be yet another way to look at the original question (possibly the most intuitive, given the title):

```
$ echo $'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 ./show 
-> "one " 
-> "two" 
-> "three and four"
```

As mentioned above, if you are using GNU `xargs` you can replace the `tr` with the GNU-specific option `-d`:

```
$ echo $'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | xargs -d\\n -n1 ./show 
-> "one " 
-> "two" 
-> "three and four"
```

Comment: looks like this is the better answer. however, i still don't quite understand what is the difference between -L and -n... can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @olala `-L` executes the command once per input line (but a space at the end of a line joins it to the next line, and the line is still split into arguments according to whitespace); while `-n` executes the command once per input argument. If you count the number of `->` in the output examples, those are the number of times the script `./show` is executed.

Comment: i see! didn't realize a space at the end of a line joins it to the next line. thanks!

Comment: *GNU `xargs` may or may not have useful extensions that allow you to do away with `tr`* It has such a very useful extension; from `xargs --help` – *-d, --delimiter=CHARACTER  items in input stream are separated by CHARACTER, not by whitespace; disables quote and backslash processing and logical EOF processing*

Comment: This answer seems confused regarding `-L`. `-L` doesn't say how many times to execute the script per line, it says how many lines of input data to consume at a time.

Comment: This is the good answer. `xargs` is very confusing and has different versions

Comment: @Tobia: Do you mind if I edit your answer to include `xargs -d '\n'` as a shortcut for `tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0` that works on "some" systems?

Comment: @krlmlr I added it.

Comment: This answer isn't completely correct either. When there is no input at all `cat /dev/null | xargs -0 -n1 echo` it still will execute the command with an empty argument. What it should be: no line, no command execution.

Comment: @tcurdt . Indeed. Maybe the answer should mention the [GNU xargs --no-run-if-empty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8296746/7015849).

Comment: L 1 with null terminated lines works fine. 
$ echo $'one \ntwo\nthree and four' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L 1 ./show.sh
-> "one " 
-> "two" 
-> "three and four"

Comment: (Continued) In other words, if the input contains spaces and is separated with new lines then both -L1 and -n1 fail, though in different ways. Once you replace new lines with null characters then both -L1 and -n1 work the same and as expected.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to run the command for *every* line (i.e. result) coming from `find`, then what do you need the `xargs` for?

Try:

`find` *path* `-type f -exec` *your-command* `{} \;`

where the literal `{}` gets substituted by the filename and the literal `\;` is needed for `find` to know that the custom command ends there.

## EDIT:

(after the edit of your question clarifying that you know about `-exec`)

From `man xargs`:

> **-L** *max-lines*
>    Use at most *max-lines* nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing
>    blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line.
>    Implies -x.

Note that filenames ending in blanks would cause you trouble if you use `xargs`:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/bax; cd /tmp/bax
$ touch a\  b c\  c
$ find . -type f -print | xargs -L1 wc -l
0 ./c
0 ./c
0 total
0 ./b
wc: ./a: No such file or directory
```

So if you don't care about the `-exec` option, you better use `-print0` and `-0`:

```
$ find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0L1 wc -l
0 ./c
0 ./c
0 ./b
0 ./a
```

Comment: I found it didactically interesting to prepend the command with echo 'find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0L1 echo wc -l'. You can then easyly preview what command xargs will generate for example see the difference if you use '-0L2'

Answer (score 25):

These two ways also work, and will work for other commands that are not using find!

```
xargs -I '{}' rm '{}'
xargs -i rm '{}'
```

example use case:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" | xargs -i rm '{}'
```

will delete all pyc files under this directory even if the pyc files contain spaces.

Comment: This issues one utility call for every element which isn't optimal.

Comment: @Gray: What's a "utility call"?

Comment: This answer works better than the top-voted answers.

Comment: One call to the application (rm in this example) per file as opposed to a number of arguments.  See my answer for a different solution.

Comment: is this portable (Posix)?

Answer (score 23):

> How can I make xargs execute the command exactly once for each line of input given?

`-L 1` is the simple solution but it does not work if any of the files contain spaces in them.  This is a key function of find's `-print0` argument – to separate the arguments by '\0' character instead of whitespace.  Here's an example:

```
echo "file with space.txt" | xargs -L 1 ls
ls: file: No such file or directory
ls: with: No such file or directory
ls: space.txt: No such file or directory
```

A better solution is to use `tr` to convert newlines to null (`\0`) characters, and then use the `xargs -0` argument.  Here's an example:

```
echo "file with space.txt" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ls
file with space.txt
```

If you then need to limit the number of calls you can use the `-n 1` argument to make one call to the program for each input:

```
echo "file with space.txt" | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 ls
```

This also allows you to filter the output of find *before* converting the breaks into nulls.

```
find . -name \*.xml | grep -v /target/ | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 tar -cf xml.tar
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in the second code block tr '\n' '\0\ => tr '\n' '\0', I tried to fix this but "Edits must be at least 6 characters" (this seems as stupid as git refusing to commit because my change was less than 6 chars)

Comment: What does this mean: "Another problem with using `-L` also is that it doesn't allow multiple arguments for each `xargs` command call. " ?

Comment: I've improved my answer to remove that extraneous info @Moberg.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative...

```
find /path -type f | while read ln; do echo "processing $ln"; done
```

Answer (score 9):

```
find path -type f | xargs -L1 command
```

is all you need.

Comment: This will not work correctly if any filenames found end in whitespace.

Answer (score 4):

The following command will find all the files (-type f) in `/path` and then copy them using `cp` to the current folder.  Note the use if `-I %` to specify a placeholder character in the `cp` command line so that arguments can be placed after the file name.

`find /path -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I % cp % .`

Tested with xargs (GNU findutils) 4.4.0

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the number of lines, or arguments (if there are spaces between each argument) using the --max-lines or --max-args flags, respectively.

> ```
>   -L max-lines
>          Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next  input
>          line.  Implies -x.
>
>   --max-lines[=max-lines], -l[max-lines]
>          Synonym  for  the -L option.  Unlike -L, the max-lines argument is optional.  If max-args is not specified, it defaults to one.  The -l option
>          is deprecated since the POSIX standard specifies -L instead.
>
>   --max-args=max-args, -n max-args
>          Use at most max-args arguments per command line.  Fewer than max-args arguments will be used if the size (see  the  -s  option)  is  exceeded,
>          unless the -x option is given, in which case xargs will exit.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

@Draemon answers seems to be right with "-0" even with space in the file.

I was trying the xargs command and I found that "-0" works perfectly with "-L". even the spaces are treated (if input was null terminated ). the following is an example :

```
#touch "file with space"
#touch "file1"
#touch "file2"
```

The following will split the nulls and execute the command on each argument in the list :

```
 #find . -name 'file*' -print0 | xargs -0 -L1
./file with space
./file1
./file2
```

so `-L1` will execute the argument on each null terminated character if used with "-0". To see the difference try :

```
 #find . -name 'file*' -print0 | xargs -0 | xargs -L1
 ./file with space ./file1 ./file2
```

even this will execute once :

```
 #find . -name 'file*' -print0  | xargs -0  | xargs -0 -L1
./file with space ./file1 ./file2
```

The command will execute once as the "-L" now doesn't split on null byte. you need to provide both "-0" and "-L" to work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I don't have enough reputation to add a comment to [Tobia's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28806991/5844631), so I am adding this "answer" to help those of us wanting to experiment with `xargs` the same way on the Windows platforms.

Here is a windows batch file that does the same thing as Tobia's quickly coded "show" script:

```
@echo off
REM
REM  cool trick of using "set" to echo without new line
REM  (from:  http://www.psteiner.com/2012/05/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line.html)
REM
if "%~1" == "" (
    exit /b
)

<nul set /p=Args:  "%~1"
shift

:start
if not "%~1" == "" (
    <nul set /p=, "%~1"
    shift
    goto start
)
echo.
```

Answer (score -3):

In your example, the point of piping the output of find to xargs is that the standard behavior of find's -exec option is to execute the command once for each found file. If you're using find, and you want its standard behavior, then the answer is simple - don't use xargs to begin with.

Comment: Actually, what I can *imply* from the OP's edits is that the input data have nothing to do with `find`, and that is why they don't prefer the `-exec` option.

Answer (score -3):

execute ant task clean-all on every build.xml on current or sub-folder.

```
find . -name 'build.xml' -exec ant -f {} clean-all \;
```

Comment: Not everyone has `ant` installed.