# perl calling xargs: end-of-line delimiter not working

Tags: perl, delimiter, xargs

I have a problem with the following code (Perl/Cygwin)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open FILE, ">", "filename.txt" or die $!;
print FILE "A\n";
print FILE "B\n";
print FILE "C\n";
close (FILE); 
system("xargs echo E < filename.txt");
```

I want it to invoke echo three times and print

```
E A
E B
E C
```

but instead it outputs

```
E A B C
```

I have tried various things with the xargs delimiter settings to no avail.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input - why didn't SO search throw this up for me?  SO does raise this as related though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try xargs -n1 echo E < filename.txt

Answer (score 1):

The 'xargs' is doing exactly what it should.  Why spawn an external process to do what Perl can do?  Instead, close your FILE and do:

```
open FILE, '<', 'filename.txt' or die $!;
while (<FILE>) {
    print "E $_";
}
```

Comment: I want to use xargs -P to run the tasks in parallel.  And I know perl can do this too.

Comment: @paperjam: Running in parallel should have been mentioned in the OP. And I hope you want to do more than just 'echo' as many of these answers focus on, since running 'echo' in parallel is pointless.

Comment: @paperjam: Then use Bil Ruppert's suggestion and add the 'P <numtasks>' argument.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was obvious that my actual script is a little more involved.  Otherwise, I'd just print the output string I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use fork:

```
my @arr = qw(A B C);
for my $c (@arr) {
  fork and next;
  exec( echo => $c );
}
```

This could use some more validation, and you can get more control over how many concurrent processes you have with something like [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager), and I assume you're really doing something more involved than 'echo'.

Comment: `xargs -P x` is already less characters than `Parallel::ForkManager` and the perfect tool for the jobs.

Comment: @paperjam - less characters? You're writing to a temp file. How many characters (and how much unnecessary work) is that?

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $file, '<', 'filename.txt' or die $!; 
while (<$file>){ 
  print "E $_"; 
}
```