# Ignore empty results for xargs in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, shell, svn, awk, xargs

The code for my website uses this piece of code for automatic deployment on the server (Ubuntu).

> `cmd = 'cd ' + checkout_dir + ' && ' + svn_command + " st | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v ^deploy | tac | xargs -r" + svn_command + " revert -R  && " + svn_command + ' up -r ' + options.revision`

What this command does is it `cd` into checkout directory, runs `svn status`, and then extracts the filename (`$2`), removes the `deploy` directory and all its files from the list (I don't want to revert it). If there are no argument it does not run the svn revert command, else it does.

Unfortunately the `xargs -r` does not work on my machine (Mac OS X 10.8). So I am stuck here, can anyone help?

Comment: Is that Python code or what?

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, the BSD implementation of `xargs` doesn't have the `-r` flag (`--no-run-if-empty`). The GNU version in Linux has it.

Here's one way to work around the issue in a way that works in both Linux and BSD:

```
... | (grep -v ^deploy || echo :) | xargs svn revert
```

The `grep ... || echo :` in the middle will generate a line with a `:` in it in case the output of `grep` is empty. It's a bit *dirty*, because `xargs` will still run the command `svn revert :`. If your repository doesn't contain the file `:` then this should have no effect, so it can be acceptable. The `:` could be anything else, as long as there is no such file in your repository.

Finally, as [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) pointed out, the `grep ... || echo :` must be enclosed within `(...)`, because:

> the `||` has higher precedence than `|`, and thus terminates the (first) pipeline.

Your code looks like a Python string. It will be more readable this way:

```
kwargs = {
  'svn': svn_command,
  'dir': checkout_dir,
  'revno': options.revision,
}
cmd = "cd {dir} && {svn} st | awk -v r=1 '$2 ! ~ /deploy/ {{ print $2; r=0 }} END {{ r || print \":\" }}' | xargs {svn} revert && {svn} up -r {revno}".format(**kwargs)
```

I made some changes to your original:

- Moved the logic of the `grep` inside `awk`, as [@tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) suggested. Notice that since the `grep` hack is not needed anymore, there is also no more need to wrap within `(...)`
- Dropped the `tac`, as I don't see the point in it
- Dropped the `-R` from `svn revert`, because I don't think you need it

Comment: How does this help at all? The problem is not empty lines, it's *no* lines.

Comment: @tripleee He wants to use the `-r` flag of `xargs`, but cannot, because it doesn't exist in BSD. He wants to use the flag because he doesn't want to run `svn revert -R` without arguments. `svn revert -R something` will revert the changes in "something" only, and `svn revert -R` without arguments would revert everything. He doesn't want to revert everything.

Comment: I understand the question. `xargs -r` is useful to suppress the action when there is no input; `grep .` does nothing to generate input when there is none (and how could it?), so the suggested workaround in this answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: @tripleee aaaaaaah, ok I see! You're absolutely right, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Still not quite there; you will need parentheses around the pipeline like `( cmds || echo : ) | xargs` because the `||` has higher precedence tjan `|` and thus terminates the (first) pipeline.

Comment: Or just factor the `echo :` into the script: `awk -v r=1 '$2 ! ~ /deploy/ { print $2; r=0 } END { r || print ":" }'`

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the tips. I improved the `awk`. Are you sure about the `( ... )` thing though? For example `ls | grep . || echo : | xargs echo` and `ls | grep nonono || echo : | xargs echo` work as expected for me: in the first one all matches reach the `xargs`, in the second the `:` reach the `xargs`. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not reaching `xargs` in the first case; use e.g. `xargs wc` instead to see this more clearly.

Comment: The macOS version of xargs seems to do `-r` by default: if there is no input, then the command is not run.

Comment: The utility `xargs` on mac supports `-r` now, while `--no-run-if-empty` is still not supported. OS Version: `Darwin 21.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 17:33:23 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64`

Answer (score 3):

Not pretty, but hopefully a workaround.

```
cmd = 'cd ' + checkout_dir + ' && ' + 
    'r=$(' svn_command + ' st | ' +
        "awk '$2 !~ /^deploy/{print $2}' | tac) && " +
    'test "$r" && ' +
    svn_command + ' revert -R $r && ' +
    svn_command + ' up -r ' + options.revision
```

I'm not convinced that the `tac` is necessary or useful. I refactored the first `grep` into the Awk script for efficiency and aesthetic reasons.

To solve the general "my `xargs` lacks `-r`" problem, the gist of the solution is to convert

```
stuff | xargs -r cmd
```

into

```
var=$(stuff)
test "$var" && cmd $var
```

The unquoted `$var` will only work if it doesn't contain file names with spaces or other surprises; but then bare-bones `xargs` without the GNU extensions suffers from the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `-r` for `xargs` isn't working on OS X, since it's a GNU extension. As for workaround, you should specify some dummy file which can be parsed by `xargs` or to not call command when there are no arguments (which can be checked before).

Method using temporary file (or any other placeholder):

```
some_cmd ... | xargs svn revert $(mktemp)
```

Using condition in shell:

```
files=$(cd checkout_dir && ... | tac)
if [ -n "$files" ]; then
    echo $files | xargs && ...
fi
```

See also: [Ignore empty result for xargs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8296710/55075)

Answer (score 1):

Bash reimplementation of `xargs` dealing with the `-r` argument:

```
#!/bin/bash
stdin=$(cat <&0)
if [[ $1 == "-r" ]] || [[ $1 == "--no-run-if-empty" ]]
then
    # shift the arguments to get rid of the "-r" that is not valid on OSX
    shift
    # wc -l return some whitespaces, let's get rid of them with tr
    linecount=$(echo $stdin | grep -v "^$" | wc -l | tr -d '[:space:]') 
    if [ "x$linecount" = "x0" ]
    then
      exit 0
    fi
fi

# grep returns an error code for no matching lines, so only activate error checks from here
set -e
set -o pipefail
echo $stdin | /usr/bin/xargs $@
```