# Don't call xargs if the previous command doesn't return anything

Tags: shell, xargs

I have the following command that checks if any new files are added and automatically calls `svn add` on all these files

```
svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

But when there are no files, `svn add` results in a warning.

How to stop from `xargs` from getting called the previous command doesn't result in any values? The solution needs to work with both GNU and BSD (Mac OS X) versions of `xargs`.

Comment: The POSIX standard for [`xargs`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html)
(building on the de facto implementations of `xargs` before the standard was set) requires the command to be executed once even if there are no file names.  Only the GNU version seems to recognize the … idiocy? … nuisance factor of that requirement.  If your code has to work on platforms with and without GNU `xargs` without installing GNU `xargs`, then you're going to have to work hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this. Not very elegant but works.

```
svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" && svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs svn add
```

Answer (score 16):

If you're running the GNU version, use `xargs -r`:

```
--no-run-if-empty  
-r
   If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.
   Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input. This option
   is a GNU extension.
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately, I need this script to work both in GNU and BSD (Mac) version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, another way is to just store outputs in arrays. And run svn only if the there is an output.

```
readarray -t OUTPUT < <(exec svn status | grep -v "^.[ \t]*\..*" | grep "^?" | awk '{print $2}')
[[ ${#OUTPUT[@]} -gt 0 ]] && svn add "${OUTPUT[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls /empty_dir/ | xargs -n10 chown root   # chown executed every 10 args
ls /empty_dir/ | xargs -L10 chown root   # chown executed every 10 lines
ls /empty_dir/ | xargs -i cp {} {}.bak   # every {} is replaced with the args from one input line
ls /empty_dir/ | xargs -I ARG cp ARG ARG.bak # like -i, with a user-specified placeholder
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19038748/1655942

Comment: Although the last 2 examples work (and allow for repeated substitution of the item to be processed), they will execute the command for every single item in the list (because of the implied `-L 1`), which could mean a performance hit when processing large lists.