# No space left on device when pulling docker image from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I am pulling a variety of docker images from my AWS, but it keeps getting stuck on the final image with the following error

```
ERROR: for <container-name>  failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): symlink libasprintf.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib64/libasprintf.so: no space left on device
ERROR: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): symlink libasprintf.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib64/libasprintf.so: no space left on device
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I have tried stopping docker, removing var/lib/docker and starting it back up again but it gets stuck at the same place

result of

> df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/nvme0n1p1  8.0G  6.5G  1.6G  81% /

devtmpfs        3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev

tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev/shm

tmpfs           3.7G   17M  3.7G   1% /run

tmpfs           3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup

tmpfs           753M     0  753M   0% /run/user/0

tmpfs           753M     0  753M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: what's output for command : df -h ?

Comment: I've put it in the question.

Comment: try to pull : `docker pull hello-world` , is this get error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue was with the EC2 instance not having enough EBS storage assigned to it. Following these steps will fix it:

- Navigate to ec2
- Look at the details of your instance and locate root device and block device
- press the path and select EBS ID
- click actions in the volume panel
- select modify volume
- enter the desired volume size (default is 8GB, shouldn’t need much more)
- ssh into instance
- run lsblk to see available volumes and note the size
- run sudo growpart /dev/volumename 1 on the volume you want to resize
- run sudo xfs_growfs /dev/volumename (the one with / in mountpoint column of lsblk)

Comment: For volumes that have a partition, such as the volumes shown in the previous step, use the growpart command to extend the partition. Notice that there is a space between the device name and the partition number.

[ec2-user ~]$ sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo growpart /dev/xvdf 1

Comment: This feels like putting a bandaid on it without addressing the real issue which in most cases would be cached docker images and / or build caches. If you change your ec2 storage size to accommodate a bunch of old docker caches without also pruning those caches, then you'll just end up having to repeat this step eventually. If you do a docker system prune (like in the answer from Nitin Nain) then normally you shouldn't ever need to modify your ec2 storage.

Answer (score 5):

It might be that the older docker images, volumes, etc. are still stuck in your EBS storage. From the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/):

> Docker takes a conservative approach to cleaning up unused objects (often referred to as “garbage collection”), such as images, containers, volumes, and networks: these objects are generally not removed unless you explicitly ask Docker to do so. This can cause Docker to use extra disk space.

SSH into your EC2 instance and verify that the space is actually taken up:

```
ssh ec2-user@<public-ip>
df -h
```

Then you can [prune](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/) the old images out:

```
docker system prune
```

Read the warning message from this command!

You can also prune the volumens. Do this if you're not storing files locally (which you shouldn't be anyway, they should be in something like AWS S3)

```
Use with Caution:

docker system prune --volumes
```

Comment: Any ideas about how to automate this (maybe using EB extension or something )for the people who are using CI/CD ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote an article about this after struggling with the same issue. If you have deployed successfully before, you may just need to add some maintenance to your deploy process. In my case, I just added cronjob to run the following:

```
docker ps -q --filter "status=exited" | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm;
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs -r docker volume rm;
```

https://medium.com/@_ifnull/aws-ecs-no-space-left-on-device-ce00461bb3cb

Comment: This was the solution for me using CDK on Mac. Note that `--no-run-if-empty` is just `-r` on Mac/BSD (and ignored as it is the default); see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8296746/5219886.