# Bash command to do nothing if no credentials exist

Tags: bash, grep, cut, xargs

I have written a command that will search Credhub to find entries that match a certain condition and then delete those matching items.  It works perfectly.  Problem is that I want this command to not do anything if it doesn't find any matches.

Here is what I have

`credhub find -n sachin | grep name: | cut -c9- | xargs -I {} credhub delete -n {}`

How can I change this to do nothing if no matches are found?

Comment: GNU `xargs` has a `-r` option

Comment: @Fravadona: Perhaps this would be worth to make an answer rather than a comment. The `-r` is an often underrated option of xargs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore xargs commands if stdin input is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296710/how-to-ignore-xargs-commands-if-stdin-input-is-empty)