# See commits between branches (git cherry) with descriptions?

Tags: git, git-log, git-cherry

The [git cherry](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-cherry.html) command is great for seeing [what commits have happened between two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/different-commits-between-two-branches). However, by default it just gives you a list of commit IDs - not that informative.

```sh
$ git cherry master dev # Commits in "dev" since it forked from "master"
+ 54408ddc6403376c638d5bfc94c033ab655da7b3
+ 68bc4277954b7de4c95881904de22f1d443366ae
+ d74ab86eee75a8e5c1a835a6e69e74c01d4186e8
```

How can I get the same list with more information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `git cherry -v master dev`

It will show commit message with commit hash.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by piping [`git cherry`](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-cherry.html) output through two more commands:

First use [`sed`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) to remove the `+` at the start of each line to leave the raw commit IDs:

```sh
$ git cherry master dev | sed 's/^+ //'
54408ddc6403376c638d5bfc94c033ab655da7b3
68bc4277954b7de4c95881904de22f1d443366ae
d74ab86eee75a8e5c1a835a6e69e74c01d4186e8
```

Now use [`xargs --max-lines=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input) to pass each commit ID to [`git log -1`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), which can then display other information about each commit:

```sh
$ git cherry master dev | sed 's/^+ //' | xargs --max-lines=1 git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h [%ad] %an : %s" --date=short
54408dd [2013-10-09] Robin Winslow : Update Binaries submodule
68bc427 [2013-10-09] Robin Winslow : Update reference dependencies for Website
d74ab86 [2013-10-09] Robin Winslow : Remove non-exisent files from Website project
```

Note: You can tailor the `--pretty=format:"%h [%ad] %an : %s" --date=short` part to get whatever output you like from `git log`