# Multiple commands with find and xargs, also accounting for special characters

Tags: bash, find, xargs

In OS X I am trying to combine the following two commands into a single command in a bash script, so that `find` operates once only. The files used by find contain spaces and special characters.

Command 1:

```
find /path -print0 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 chmod -N
```

Command 2:

```
find /path -print0 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 xattr -c
```

Both the above commands work.

I understand from '[Make xargs execute the command once for each line of input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input)' that multiple commands can be executed through `xargs` with something like

```
find /path -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'command1 {} ; command2 {}'
```

However, my attempt to combine the commands with

```
find /path -print0 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'chmod -N {} ; xattr -c {}'
```

results in multiple errors for each file and folder in the `/path`, such as

```
chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file {}: No such file or directory
xattr: No such file: {}
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Is anyone able to help? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
find /path -exec sh -c 'chmod -N "$@"; xattr -c "$@"' - {} +
```

- `-exec ... +`, passes (typically) *all* matching paths to the specified command, which is them most efficient approach.

  - Both `chmod` and `xattr` support multiple file operands, so this approach is feasible.
  - `find` properly retains argument boundaries when passing substituting the paths for `{}`, so it would even handle filenames with embedded newlines correctly.
    <sup>Incidentally: I'm unclear on what the purpose of `tr '\n', '\0'` in your code is, given that you already output `\0`-separated paths thanks to `-print0`.</sup>
- Note the `-` as the first (dummy) argument passed to `sh -c`, because the first argument will become `$0`.

---

As for the problem with your original command:

I can't explain the specific symptoms, but one problem is that you're not quoting the `{}` instances inside your shell command, which makes them subject to word splitting (breaks file paths with embedded spaces into multiple arguments).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-exec bash` instead of `-exec sh`, just to be explicit (OP is using bash)?

Comment: @Sumit: The OP's original command uses `sh`, so I stuck with it. In practice, given the specific command, it doesn't make a difference. It wouldn't make a difference even on other platforms, given that the entire command is POSIX-compliant.