# How to perform a static count of loaded packages in R?

Tags: r, org-mode, xargs

I'd like to search a directory structure to count the number of times I've loaded various R packages.  The source is contained in .org and .R files.  I'm willing to assume that "library(" is the first non-blank entry on any line I care about, and I'm willing to assume that there is at most only one such call per line.

```
 find . -regex ".*/.*\.org" -print
```

gets me a list of .org files, and

```
find . -regex ".*\.\(org\|R\)$" -print
```

gets me a list of .org and .R files (thanks to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15308/how-to-use-find-command-to-search-for-multiple-extensions).

Given a particular file,

```
grep -h "library(" file | sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//'
```

gets me the package name. I'd like to hook them together and then possibly redirect the output to a file, from which I can use R to calculate frequencies.

The seemingly straightforward

```
find . -regex ".*/.*\.org" -print | xargs -0 grep -h "library("  | sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//'
```

doesn't work; I get

```
 find . -regex ".*/.*\.org" -print | xargs -0 grep -h "library("  |   sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//'
Usage: /usr/bin/grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try '/usr/bin/grep --help' for more information.
```

and I'm not sure what to do next.

I also tried

```
find . -regex ".*/.*\.org" -exec grep -h "library(" "{}" "\;"
```

and got

```
find . -regex ".*/.*\.org" -exec grep -h "library(" "{}" "\;"
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

It seems simple.  What am I missing?

UPDATE: Adding -t to the above xargs shows me the first command:

```
grep -h library ./dirname/filename.org
```

followed by, presumably, a list of all the matching files with paths relative to the PWD.  Actually, that works if I only search for .org files; if I add .R files, too, I get "xargs: argument line too long".  I think that means xargs is passing the entire list of files as the argument to one invocation of grep.

Comment: If it helps, find . -regex ".*\.\(org\|R\)$" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h 'library'
returns 
Usage: /usr/bin/grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try '/usr/bin/grep --help' for more information.
Usage: /usr/bin/grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try '/usr/bin/grep --help' for more information.   If I only use one extension, I get only the first two error lines.

Comment: I thought http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input had the answer, but I couldn't make it work.  find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(org\|R\)$" -exec  grep -h 'library(' '{}' ';' | sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//' | sed 's/\"//g' does seem to work, though I'm sure there are more elegant and concise approaches.

Comment: `find . -type f -regex ".*\.\(org\|R\)" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -h "library(" | sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//'` seems to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

`find ... -print | xargs` OK

`find ... -print0 | xargs -0` OK

`find ... -print0 | xargs` broken

`find ... -print | xargs -0` broken (what you used)

Also, please don't:

`grep -h "library(" | sed 's/library(//' | sed 's/)//'`

when this is faster:

`grep -h "library(" | sed -e 's/library(//' -e 's/)//'`

and this is even faster, and more interesting:

`grep -h "library(" | grep -o '(.*)' | tr -d ' ()'`