# pipe printf command output into other command's path argument

Tags: pipe, printf, xargs

i read out directory paths and try to pipe them into a comand with parameter -f

the individual commands look like this

```
printf '%s\n' /mnt/convert/*
convert -f /mnt/convert/example.mp4
```

the output of printf might be:

```
/mnt/convert/vid1.mp4
/mnt/convert/vid2.mp4
/mnt/convert/vid3.mp4
...
```

the goal is (pseudocode):

```
printf '%s\n' /mnt/convert/* | xargs convert -f
```

how would I best achieve this? right now I receive the error:
`Error: Got unexpected extra argument (/mnt/convert/vid1.mp4)`

Comment: See linked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199266/make-xargs-execute-the-command-once-for-each-line-of-input, you should run `xargs -n1 ...` to run `convert -f` each time for every input line(s)

Comment: lol thank you, the exact same question I already found and linked to the issue