# How to pipe a text file with very long lines to a script line-by-line?

Tags: bash, split, pipe

I want to run a script on each line of an input file/stream in bash. This is simple when the lines are short:

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line" | ./process.sh; done < input.txt
```

However, the lines are very long (several MiB) so I cannot use `read` any more. This works:

```
split -l1 < input.txt
for file in x??; do ./process.sh < "$file"; done
rm x??
```

but it's very slow as it creates temporary files.

Is there a way to pipe the input lines directly to `process.sh` so that the script is invoked once per line?

Answer (score 2):

Given this input file:

```
$ cat file
foo bar
etc
```

Try this with GNU xargs (using `awk '{print "<"$0">"}'` as `./process.sh`):

```
$ < file xargs -I {} -d'\n' -n1 printf '%s\n' '{}' | awk '{print "<"$0">"}'
<foo bar>
<etc>
```

or this otherwise:

```
$ tr '\n' '\0' < file | xargs -I {} -0 -n1 printf '%s\n' '{}' | awk '{print "<"$0">"}'
<foo bar>
<etc>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28806991/1745001 for an explanation.

Comment: In both cases, the line is an argument to process.sh, which has a size limit. Is there a way to get the line at stdin?

Answer (score 1):

GNU `parallel`, different from `xargs`, is capable of sending the data to the standard input of the command instead of passing it as arguments. So you could try:

```
parallel -j1 -N1 --pipe ./process.sh < input.txt
```

`-j1` for one job at a time only. Use `-jN` to run `N` jobs in parallel, or `-j+0` to run as many jobs as you have cores on your computer.

`-N1` to pass one line per job.

`--pipe` to send the data to the standard input of the command instead of passing it as command arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try sed:

```
$ cat file
one
two
tre

$ sed 's/.*/echo "|&|"/e' file
|one|
|two|
|tre|
```

In your case it would be like:

```
$ sed 's|.*|./process.sh "&"|e' file
```

Awk can also run commands, but I bet awk alone can do what you need.

Comment: sed's /e flags makes its output an argument of the command to execute, which has a size limit

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the `while read ...` code in the question with input lines of 8MB and it works fine.  I assume your issue is that it is too slow.

If you can use Perl then this code shows one way to do it:

```
perl -Mautodie -nle "open P, '| ./process.sh'; print P; close P" input.txt
```

- The `-Mautodie` causes the code to fail with error messages if any file or pipe operations fail.  Although the `autodie` module has been a core module in Perl for over a decade, it may not be available in some Perl installations.  Some are very old.  Others (for unknown reasons) don't include all core modules.  The code will work if you remove `-Mautodie`, but it may fail silently if something goes wrong.

If Python is an option, this code may be of use:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' python_code <<'_END_PYTHON_CODE_'
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

for line in sys.stdin:
    with Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdin=PIPE, text=True) as p:
        p.stdin.write(line)
_END_PYTHON_CODE_

python -c "$python_code" ./process.sh <input.txt
```

- I don't have much experience of Python, so the code may not be good.  It runs slightly slower than the Perl code in my testing.